# Getting an Error - encryption command failed when sending pgp encrpted email using enigmail

Tags: encryption, gnupg, thunderbird

`$gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.10
libgcrypt 1.8.3`

Running Enigmail version 2.0.8 (20180804-1515) 
Thunderbird 60.0 (64-bit) - Manjaro 1.0

When I try to send an encrypted email to myself, it just gives this error: `Error - encryption command failed

[image]

And since this message doesn't contain any helpful information, Where can I to find the error log?
and also if I save the message as draft, it saves as encrypted message in server with no issue.
I only get this error when I send a PGP (gpg) encrypted or signed email.

Comment: If the problem still exists, try this answer. [I managed to resolve it this way.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57948183/8296094)