# Enigmail Error - "no matching secret key found to decrypt message"

Tags: gnupg, thunderbird

After switching the Linux Distributions, gpg changed and I could not encrypt any emails. Even my own. Enigmail gave me "No matching secret key found to decrypt message" error message.

Before:

```
$gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.18
libgcrypt 1.7.6-beta
```

Now:

```
$gpg2 --version 
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.13
libgcrypt 1.8.4
```

Both have Enigmail 2.0.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been long time since you wrote. Nevertheless I'd try to give it a chance, as I think similar problem still might happen (again).

1. First of all try this command:

   gpg-agent --daemon

Expectation is, it would show you if something is wrong with config file(s). Example output:

```
gpg-agent[22861]: /home/<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME>/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:13: invalid option
```

This, for example, is telling you: "Line 13 in that file contains invalid setting option".
In this case, edit that file, remediate the error or comment out the line creating the error for example like this:

2. Edit the file. Example, in your console/terminal, try one of this:

   nano /home/REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

   gedit /home/REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

   editor /home/REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
3. now go to that line (here in the example it is line 13), and replace its content, example

   ignore-caching-for-signing

with the line

```
# ignore-caching-for-signing
```

Plsease note the '#' in front of the line, which is the comment sign to deactivate the invalid option.

4. Go to line 1. above and repeat the gpg-agent command, and the steps up to this line, until the gpg-agent starts without complaining about invalid options

   gpg-agent --daemon
5. Now start thunderbird with enigmail, and click on the encrypted mail. From my experience, you should now be able to see its content.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this helped: https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/forum/support/thread/03ebee57/

```
gpg2 --edit-key 0xYourKeyId setpref save
```

(`0xYourKeyId` taken from `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`)

EDIT: ok, this does not work. I can decrypt messages for like 5 minutes since I had to unlock the keychain in the dialog.